# Azure function with table Storage - update entity not working

Tags: azure-functions, azure-table-storage

I have this code:

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"
#r "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage"
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table;
public async static void Run(string myIoTHubMessage, ICollector<SensorData> tableOutput, CloudTable activityTable,ICollector<SensorData> activityValue, ILogger log)
{
    var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IoTMessage>(myIoTHubMessage);
    string temp =  data.param2;
    double temperature = double.Parse(temp) * 0.01;

    var sensor = new SensorData { Temperature = temperature.ToString(),DeviceId = data.deviceId, RowKey = data.messageId, PartitionKey = data.deviceId };
    tableOutput.Add(sensor);

    var query = new TableQuery<SensorValue>().Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, data.deviceId.ToString()));
    var segment = await activityTable.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(query, null);

    if (segment.Results.Count == 0)
    {
        activityValue.Add(sensor);
    }
    else
    {
        SensorValue sensorValue = new SensorValue
        {
            PartitionKey = data.deviceId,
            RowKey = data.messageId,
            Temperature = Convert.ToInt16(temperature),
        };

        var operation = TableOperation.Replace(sensorValue);
        await activityTable.ExecuteAsync(operation);
        log.LogInformation(segment.Results.Count.ToString());
    }
}
public class SensorData
{
    public string RowKey { get; set; }
    public string PartitionKey { get; set; }
    public string Temperature { get; set; }
    public string DeviceId {get; set;}
}

public class IoTMessage
{
    public string messageId { get; set; }
    public string temperature { get; set; }
    public string deviceId { get; set; }

}

public class SensorValue : TableEntity
{
    public string RowKey { get; set; }
    public string PartitionKey { get; set; }
    public string Temperature { get; set; }
    public string DeviceId { get; set; }
}
```

The function works in such a way that it gets data from sensors and saves them to the base, but I would like to make a second table in which only the last request of a given device will be saved. I check if there is a device in the table with such an id as there is no added, and it works without a problem. Unfortunately, I have a problem with updating a given record. It looks like this to me:

```
   if (segment.Results.Count == 0)
        {
            activityValue.Add(sensor);
        }
        else
        {
            SensorValue sensorValue = new SensorValue
            {
                PartitionKey = data.deviceId,
                RowKey = data.messageId,
                Temperature = Convert.ToInt16(temperature),
            };

            var operation = TableOperation.Replace(sensorValue);
            await activityTable.ExecuteAsync(operation);
            log.LogInformation(segment.Results.Count.ToString());
        }
```

Recording itself in the case when there is no such device in the activityTable table works without any problems, unfortunately update in case when there is such a device does not work, ie no errors, but also no record update :(

In my case, in the activityTable, PartitionKey to deviceId table sent in request. I try to do it from 8 am, but nothing is working, and I can not deal with it :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fast solution: set the `ETag` field to be `*`, as you can see in the Azure Tips & Tricks article [Updating an item from a Azure Storage Table](https://microsoft.github.io/AzureTipsAndTricks/blog/tip85.html).

The slightly longer version: the entity you're trying to replace doesn't exist according to Table Storage, since you omitted the `ETag` value.

> An **ETag** property is used for optimistic concurrency during updates. It is not a timestamp as there is another property called **TimeStamp** that stores the last time a record was updated. For example, if you load an entity and want to update it, the ETag must match what is currently stored. This is important b/c if you have multiple users editing the same item, you don't want them overwriting each other's changes.

Setting the ETag to be `*` is actually setting it to a wildcard that accepts any value.